# Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubygems, bundler

Been trying to run `bundle install` for a rails app and keep getting the error below. I am the only user on this machine running Windows 10.

```
Fetching marcel 0.3.2
Installing marcel 0.3.2
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen -
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/marcel-0.3.2/test/fixtures/magic/video/quicktime/quicktime.mov
An error occurred while installing marcel (0.3.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install marcel -v '0.3.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.
```

Note that I have confirmed that I have full access to the folder and here is the command line output:

```

```
~/.bundle zbw $ ls -al
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 1 zbw 1049089 0 Feb 16  2018 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 zbw 1049089 0 Sep  9 00:28 ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 zbw 1049089 0 Feb 16  2018 cache/

/c/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/marcel-0.3.2/test/fixtures/magic/video/quicktime zbw $ ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 zbw 1049089 0 Sep  7 16:02 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 zbw 1049089 0 Sep  7 16:02 ../

/c/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/marcel-0.3.2/test/fixtures/magic/video zbw $ ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 zbw 1049089 0 Sep  7 16:02 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 zbw 1049089 0 Sep  7 16:02 ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 zbw 1049089 0 Sep  7 16:02 mp4/
drwxr-xr-x 1 zbw 1049089 0 Sep  7 16:02 quicktime/
```

```

Comment: Did you check the permissions on `~/.bundle` directory ? If the permission is set to `root`, you'll have to change it I suppose.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna confirmed that I have permissions:
`drwxr-xr-x 1 zbw 1049089       0 Feb 16  2018  .bundle/`

Answer (score 1):

this is due to folder permission error.

give create file folder permissions to that particular directory.